# How to make a parent - child taxonomy list

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

How can I make a category page displaying all my 100+ taxonomy terms in a parent/child way (something just like http://www.dmoz.org/)?

```
-parent
--child
--child
-parent
...
```

Comment: resolved
1. Create View 
Show - Taxonomy terms - of type ...  

2. Add relationship 
Taxonomy term: Parent term

3. Add field
Taxonomy term: Name ( use relationship - Parent term )
* hide from display

4. Set format
Grid/ul/li...
Grouping field -> (Parent) Taxonomy term: Name

Answer (score 2):

Yes above answer works, but parent terms are showed at top of view, so it's nice to remove them. I use Views Hacks module , and only check Selective Exposed Filters.
For filter select Taxonomy term: Parent (selective) and choose is not one of all
You can view my view at http://www.attorney-directory.net/practice-areas