# Hierarchical Taxonomy list pages

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 7

I'm developing a site which has 3 levels of taxonomy terms, something like:

Products -> Subcat1 -> Subcat2 -> Item

I've created a view with a page for the taxonomy vocabulary which has a contextual filter configured when a filter value is not in the URL to use the fixed value ''. This page displays the first level of taxonomy terms as expected which is great, however I would like to link the first level to the next level of terms but after 3 days of trying I'm still no closer to figuring it out.

Can anyone shed any light on how this can be achieved? I'm still learning Drupal so it's more than possible I've missed something obvious.

So essentially what I'm after is this:

Top-level page:

```
Fruits
Nuts
Sweets
```

Clicking on fruits shows:

```
Citrus
Non-citrus
```

Clicking on Citrus shows:

```
Lemon
Lime
```

The final page above is a list of actual content items, not taxonomy terms. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: link to the taxonomy overview page for that term (like /taxonomy/termX), or do you want to stay in the view ?

Comment: maybe check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23557/how-to-make-a-parent-child-taxonomy-list

Comment: If I link to taxonomy/termX I get a page that says no items are classified with that perticular term, what I need is a list of sub-terms. I followed the instructions in the link which gives me a nested view of the terms/subterms but it's not quite what I'm after. I'll update the question to give more details.

Answer (score 2):

So i have similar issue, and i solve this by creating 2 views.
First view show taxonomy terms and i group them by theirs parents (add relationship Taxonomy term: Parent)
Second View is override on taxonomy/term/% and i add more Context (Arguments) for each level add an argument, and finally i add into header another view, who shows only children terms of current term.

You can view my work at http://www.attorney-directory.net/practice-areas